# How to remove comment from JSON?

Tags: php, android, json, webserver

Not really sure how to ask this, but I have an Android application which uses PHP for registration/login of a users into a mysql database on my server online. Everything worked fine on my localhost with WAMP but now I am getting a JSON exception.

Here is my Android LogCat:

```
 01-21 01:55:17.054: E/JSON Parser(3688): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException:     Unterminated comment at character 5 of 
 01-21 01:55:17.054: E/JSON Parser(3688): /*Success... Localhost via UNIX socket
 01-21 01:55:17.054: E/JSON Parser(3688):    {"tag":"login","success":1,"error":0,"uid":"52de1579866ce2.84736550","user":{"name":"test","email":"test@hotmail.com","created_at":"2014-01-20 23:36:41","updated_at":null}}
```

From what I understand the problem is the /*Success....Localhost via UNIX socket, but I have no idea how to remove this....my php file does not add this and I don't really know what to do.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

---

EDIT: Added PHP Code/Files

### index.php

```
 <?php
if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
// get tag
$tag = $_POST['tag'];

// include db handler
require_once 'include/db_functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// response Array
$response = array("tag" => $tag, "success" => 0, "error" => 0);

// check for tag type
if ($tag == 'login') {
    // Request type is check Login
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // check for user
    $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);
    if ($user != false) {
        // user found
        // echo json with success = 1
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
        $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user not found
        // echo json with error = 1
        $response["error"] = 1;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect email or password!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else if ($tag == 'register') {
    // Request type is Register new user
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // check if user is already existed
    if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
        // user is already existed - error response
        $response["error"] = 2;
        $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed";
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // store user
        $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);
        if ($user) {
            // user stored successfully
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
            $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
            $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user failed to store
            $response["error"] = 1;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Registartion";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid Request";
}
} else {
echo "Access Denied";
}
?>
```

### db_functions.php

```
 <?php
class DB_Functions {

private $db;
//put your code here
// constructor
function __construct() {
    require_once 'db_connect.php';
    // connecting to database
    $this->db = new DB_Connect();
    $this->db->connect();
}
// destructor
function __destruct() {

}
/**
 * Storing new user
 * returns user details
 */
public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO autoTracker_users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");
    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        // get user details 
        $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM autoTracker_users WHERE uid = $uid");
        // return user details
        return mysql_fetch_array($result);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
/**
 * Get user by email and password
 */
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM autoTracker_users WHERE email = '$email'") or die(mysql_error());
    // check for result 
    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $salt = $result['salt'];
        $encrypted_password = $result['encrypted_password'];
        $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
        // check for password equality
        if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
            // user authentication details are correct
            return $result;
        }
    } else {
        // user not found
        return false;
    }
}
/**
 * Check user is existed or not
 */
public function isUserExisted($email) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT email from autoTracker_users WHERE email = '$email'");
    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        // user existed 
        return true;
    } else {
        // user not existed
        return false;
    }
}
/**
 * Encrypting password
 * @param password
 * returns salt and encrypted password
 */
public function hashSSHA($password) {

    $salt = sha1(rand());
    $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
    $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
    $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
    return $hash;
}
/**
 * Decrypting password
 * @param salt, password
 * returns hash string
 */
public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

    $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

    return $hash;
}
}
?>
```

### db_connect.php

```
 <?php
class DB_Connect {
// constructor
function __construct() {

}
// destructor
function __destruct() {
    // $this->close();
}
// Connecting to database
public function connect() {
    // connecting to mysql
    $con = mysql_connect('servername', 'user', 'pass');
    // selecting database
    mysql_select_db('database');

    // return database handler 69.195.124.151
    return $con;
}
// Closing database connection
public function close() {
    mysql_close();
}
}
?>
```

db_connect and db_functions are inside an include folder, hence why I refer to them as 'include/db_functions.php' inside index.php.

When I register a user it correctly inserts the record into my database however, the login portion fails because of that /*Success line. When I use localhost instead of my online server, it works fine. Thanks for the help!

### Edit #2:

I am using my own JSON parser class which works fine when using WAMP and localhost, I only get this error when I have the PHP on a bluehost website with MySql db.

```
public class JSONParser_Helpers {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser_Helpers() {

}

/**----------------------------
 * Return JSON result from URL
 * @param URL
 *----------------------------- */
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        //Log.e("Register URL Parser Class: ", url);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        //Log.e("HTTP Response: ", httpResponse.toString());
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
        Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}
}
```

### Edit #3:

I figured it out but perhaps not the best way...I just edited an IF Statement into my JSON Parser class so that if the line starts with "/" such as the one which is causing my issue does, and now it works fine. If you have any better ideas for this, please let me know!

```
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!line.startsWith("/")) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                //Log.e("LINE: ", line);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think its related to some ' which needs to be escaped

Comment: can you post full code for further rectifying

Comment: Your php code adds it. Definitely.

Comment: Sorry for the delay guys, I just added my PHP code. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

android  cannot parser this json ，because this JSON parser library Check the very strict. you can try modify renturn json string such as 
{"tag":"login",**"success":"1","error":"0"**,"uid":"52de1579866ce2.84736550","user":{"name":"test","email":"test@hotmail.com","created_at":"2014-01-20 23:36:41","updated_at":null}}

Comment: I have my own JSON parser class which works fine when I use localhost and WAMP...the error is when I use a hosted website and MySQL database...EDIT: I just realized what you are saying, I will modify that and try again. Thanks!

Comment: I tried changing my PHP to return "success":"1","error":"0" but that still doesnt work. I think the error is with this line "/*Success... Localhost via UNIX socket"